# Как установить кодировку ansi или oem на centos?

Tags: кодировка, centos7, ansi

Коллеги, просьба подсказать как установить кодировку ansi или oem на centos.

Comment: Где конкретно это нужно? Зачем вам это? Чего вы хотите добиться этими кодировками?

Comment: Платформа 1С стоит на Windows, 1с сервер на Centos. 1С работает только с ansi и oem. В данном случаи у меня не стоят эти кодировки на линуксе, поэтому в базе я вижу не корректный текст.

Comment: centos здесь абсолютно ни при чём, все вопросы по кодировкам к используемым вами программам — к 1C, к базе, к программе которой вы смотрите базу, чем вы там ещё пользуетесь

Comment: Проблема в СУБД, все БД ru_RU.UTF-8, а должно быть в Win1251. Возможно есть у кого то опыт как создать БД с данной кодировкой?

Comment: Подскажите как добавить Win1251 в Postgre?